# python script does not rewrite the file on itself

Tags: python, file, text, line

so first and foremost i wanted to connect multiple lines into one and add ","

so in example

```
line1
line2
line2
```

to

```
line1,line2,line3
```

i managed to make it work with this script right here

```
filelink = input("Enter link here ")

fix = file = open(filelink, "r")

data=open(filelink).readlines()
for n,line in enumerate(data):
    if line.startswith("line"):
       data[n] = "\n"+line.rstrip()
    else:
       data[n]=line.rstrip()
print(','.join(data))
```

HOWEVER in the terminal itself it shows it executed perfectly but in the text file itself it's still remains the same no connected lines and no commas

side note. i would love some explanations how does the loop work and what "enumerate" stands for and why specifically this code i tried googling each one separately and understand the code but i didn't manage to find what i was looking for if anyone keen to explain the code line by line shortly i would be very appreciative

Thanks in advance <3

Comment: Well the first thing is that you opened the file in "read" mode with "r" so its contents can never change - you never wrote anything back out. `print` does not write to a file, it writes to the system `stdout`, which just displays in your console

Comment: any hints what i should change ?

Comment: Open the file again in write mode once you've read the data in and swapped the newlines for commas

Comment: At some point in between, you need to close the file, too. Use a context manager to handle files. All of this would be in a good tutorial before asking on SO

Comment: if i change the "r" to "w" it basically deletes everything from the file

Comment: "Open the file again in write mode once you've read the data in and swapped the newlines for commas". I didn't say that you should open in write mode from the start; I was very specific with my wording

Comment: I Am very new to python and i still don't understand i am sorry can you elaborate more on that ?

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat superfluous:

```
fix = file = open(filelink, "r")
```

That's assigning two names to the same file object, and you don't even use `fix`, so at least drop that part.

For handling files, you would be better using a [context manager](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html). That means that you can open a resource and they will automatically get closed for you once you're done (usually).

In any case, you opened in `read` mode with `open(filelink, "r")` so you'll never change the file contents. `print(','.join(data))` will probably show you what you expect, but `print()` writes to `stdout` and the change will only be in your terminal. You will *not* modify the base file with this. But, I think you're sufficiently close that I'll try close the missing connection.

In this case, you need to:

1. open the file first in read mode to pull the data out.
2. Do the transform in python to the data
3. Open the file again in write mode (which wipes the existing contents)
4. Write the transformed data

So, like this:

```
filelink = input("Enter link here ")

with open(filelink) as infile: # context manager, by default in "r" mode
    data = [item.strip() for item in infile.readlines()]

data = ','.join(data)

# Now write it back out

with open(filelink, "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write(data)
```

Comment: ahh i see i appreciate the lecture and help :D